# Duplicate folder, subfolders and contents multiple times to multiple folders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to copy a 'template' folder structure within a Google Shared Drive (Team Drive).

It looks something like this:

```
+------------------------+-----------+-------------+
|       Top Level        | 2nd Level |  3rd Level  |
+------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| MASTER TEMPLATE FOLDER |           | FILE 1      |
|                        |           | FILE 2      |
|                        |           |             |
|                        | FOLDER 1  | F1 File Foo |
|                        |           | F1 File Bar |
|                        |           | F1 File Baz |
|                        |           |             |
|                        | FOLDER 2  | F2 File Foo |
|                        |           | F2 File Bar |
|                        |           |             |
|                        | FOLDER 3  | F3 File Foo |
|                        |           | F3 File Boo |
|                        |           | F3 File Baz |
|                        |           |             |
|                        | FOLDER 4  | F4 File Foo |
|                        |           | F4 File Bar |
|                        |           | F4 File Baz |
|                        |           | F4 File Qux |
+------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Shared Drive has the following folders:
_Automation, _Templates, Person 1, Person 2, Person 3.

I need to create a folder at the start of each week for each person, and inside that weekly folder, I need to be 3 copies of this template folders.

I have a (mostly) working version of the code.
It works fine if you are just copying the template from the template folder structure once to 1 folder.

As you'll see, we call a function called removeTriggers_ to kill our continuation, but this causes an issue as the trigger is called resume_ and is used each time the script starts to run.

So what is happening is:

1. Start
2. Gets Person folder ID by getting all the top level folders and excluding the necessary
3. Create a Weekly Folder in each Person folder.
4. If a weekly folder exists, create 3 Case Folders
5. Start the copy template process for each case folder
6. Creates a resume_ trigger for each case folder
7. resume_ trigger fires and picks up continuation token but then wipes out all other triggers.

Really not sure the best way to tackle this.

Not going to post it here, as it's fairly chunky but here is a link to the GAS:

https://script.google.com/d/1ORKHQn_9j6kaUNsCK0D6stPLcjUlltAZM5bqmm-taU7OfHWZdlYIlOuK/edit?splash=yes

To recap - What should happen is:

1. Get folder ID for each 'Person' folder
2. Create a Weekly Folder for each 'Person'
3. Create 3 'Case' folders for each Weekly folder
4. Copy the template folder files and folder structure into each 'Case' folder

Comment: Are setting up the resume triggers really necessary? If I understand correctly you should be able to just make a call to get all the fileIDs recursively from Templates and copy them in to each of the Person folders and then set up an installable Trigger for it to run once a week.